# Cypress. Ошибка сценария с перекрестным происхождением

Tags: javascript, test-automation, cypress

Всем привет, решил изучить Cypress для авто-тестов и столкнулся с проблемой: при прогоне тестов возникает ошибка "Cypress detected that an uncaught error was thrown from a cross origin script.", говорящая о том, что "Cypress обнаружил, что неперехваченная ошибка была вызвана сценарием с перекрестным происхождением.". Я исследовал сайт с документацией Cypress, установил в config-файле chromeWebSecurity в значение false. Это не помогло. Есть люди с опытом на Cypress? Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
describe('My Third Test', () => {
  it('Do it', () => {
    cy.visit('https://demoqa.com/checkbox');
    
    cy.xpath('//*[@id="tree-node"]/ol/li/span/button').click();
    cy.xpath('//*[@id="tree-node"]/ol/li/ol/li[2]/span/button').click();
    cy.xpath('//*[@id="tree-node"]/ol/li/ol/li[2]/ol/li[1]/span/button').click();
    cy.xpath('//*[@id="tree-node"]/ol/li/ol/li[2]/ol/li[1]/ol/li[1]/span/label/span[1]').click();
    cy.xpath('//*[@id="result"]/span[2]').should('have.text', 'react');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение, хоть и костыльное. Ответ добавил для тех, кто вдруг столкнется с такой же проблемой.
Необходимо добавить в тест(между 'describe' и 'it'):

```
  Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
    // returning false here prevents Cypress from
    // failing the test
    return false
})
```